# Find sum of values using group

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sum the customer count of which have total quantity is 2, The table i have is below

| Customer | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Anju | 1 |
| Anu | 2 |
| Lalson | 1 |
| Anju | 1 |
| sujatha | 2 |
| Lalson | 1 |
| Appu | 2 |
| Anaya | 1 |

In the above table I need the customer count as 5
that is

| Customer | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Anju | 2 |
| Anu | 2 |
| Lalson | 2 |
| sujatha | 2 |
| Appu | 2 |
| Anaya | 1 |

so final value is 5, i need count of customers who have quantity as 2,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select customer, sum(quantity) as quantity
      from t
      group by customer
     ) c
where quantity = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT Customer
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Customer
    HAVING SUM(Quantity) = 2
) t;
```

### Demo

Note that it is preferable to do the filtering on sum of quantity inside the subquery, to avoid bringing unnecessary records into the outer subquery.